# Pacemaker - standby or active?

Tags: pacemaker, crm

Hello id like to make 100% sure about one thing regarding pacemaker. There is going to be maint night tonigh and id like to be completly sure we can shut down server. It is supposed to be in standby using pacemaker, but i have only verbal assurance from admin.

This is crm status output

```
Full list of resources:

 Clone Set: nginx_cdn_http_clone [nginx_cdn_http]
     Started: [ stor0-brn stor0-iva stor1-brn stor1-iva ]
 Clone Set: redis_clone [redis]
     Started: [ stor0-brn stor0-iva stor1-brn stor1-iva ]
 vip_stor_0 (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started stor0-iva 
 vip_stor_1 (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started stor0-iva
```

Is it that stor0-brn is in standby mode, so its ready to be shutdown for a maint? Its matter of rather double-triple check. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You didn't look at the right status, you'll have to check node status.

I set my cluster `node1` to standby and it looks like this:

```
[...]
2 nodes configured
11 resources configured

Node node1: standby
Online: [ node2 ]

Full list of resources:

 Master/Slave Set: ms_res1 [ms_res1]
     Masters: [ node2 ]
     Stopped: [ node1 ]
 res_Filesystem_xxx  (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Started node2
 [...]
```

<strike>Looking at your resources, nothing seems to be running exclusively on `stor0-brn`, but I / we cannot say for sure!</strike>

As your output states:

```
Started: [ stor0-brn stor0-iva stor1-brn stor1-iva ]
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

I'd say `stor0-brn` is still online, not in standby.

Are you the one responsible for the shutdown? If yes, never trust the word of others and check for yourself (or *with* others, as you are doing right now).